# Get IP address of a LibPcapLiveDevice

Tags: c#, mono, libpcap, sharppcap

Since the SharpPcap project claims to be compatible with Mono I decided to get my project running on a Mac.

For this I had to make the `WinPcapDevice` a `LibPcapLiveDevice` and map the `WinPcap.dll` to the `libpcap.dylib`.

SharpPcap.dll.config:

```
<configuration>
    <dllmap dll="wpcap" target="libpcap.1.6.2.dylib" />
</configuration>
```

code:

```
private static string GetFilterString(ICaptureDevice captureDevice)
{
    var device = (LibPcapLiveDevice) captureDevice; 
    return String.Format("((tcp dst port 80) and (src net {0})) or ((dst net {0}) and (tcp src port 80))", device.Addresses[1]);
}
```

Problem is, that the property `device.Addresses` is empty and I can't find any other property that would contain the IP address. Actually almost all properties are empty, except for the device name and its MAC address. 
I'm not sure wether this is a problem caused by SharpPcap or Libpcap.

**EDIT**

As Guy Harris suggested I compared the structs and types used in the `PcapUnmanagedStructures.cs` with the Apple OS Reference Docs. I tried to adapt them, so they would match the OS' specification:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct sockaddr 
{
    public byte       sa_family;      /* address family */
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=14)]
    public byte[]       sa_data;        /* 14 bytes of protocol address */
};

public struct in_addr
{
    public UInt32 s_addr; //in_addr_t
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct sockaddr_in
{
    public byte       sa_family;      /* address family */
    public UInt16       sa_port;        /* port */
    public in_addr      sin_addr;       /* address */

    // char sin_zero[8]; not sure this whether to add this as it was contained in the doc

    // pad the size of sockaddr_in out to 16 bytes
    MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=8)]
    // Disable warnings around this unused field
    #pragma warning disable 0169
    private byte[]       pad; // not sure about this one either
    #pragma warning restore 0169
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct sockaddr_in6
{
    public byte       sin6_family;    /* address family */
    public UInt16       sin6_port;      /* Transport layer port # */
    public UInt32       sin6_flowinfo;  /* IPv6 flow information */

   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=32)] // raised it to 32 as the struct in6_addr contains an element of type __uint32_t
   public byte[]       sin6_addr;      /* IPv6 address */ 
   public UInt32       sin6_scope_id;  /* scope id (new in RFC2553) */
};
```

I'm not sure I did it right, since the `ipAddress` is still empty:
[image: screenshot]

**EDIT 2**

Guy Harris was right about that lenght field. This is what works for me now:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct sockaddr 
{
    public byte          sa_len;
    public byte      sa_family;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=14)]
    public byte[]    sa_data;
};

public struct in_addr
{
    public UInt32 s_addr;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct sockaddr_in
{
    public byte         sin_len;
    public byte         sin_family;
    public UInt16       sin_port;
    public in_addr      sin_addr;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=8)]
    public byte         sin_zero;
};
```

Note that I also changed some field's name prefix from `sa` to `sin`. I also changed the `pad`'s name to `sin_zero`. Quite easy after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not familiar with C#, but, if [PcapUnmanagedStructures.cs](http://sourceforge.net/p/sharppcap/code/ci/master/tree/SharpPcap/LibPcap/PcapUnmanagedStructures.cs) is attempting to describe the layout of the *native C* structures for the OS, those declarations aren't correct for many UN*Xes, including BSD-flavored UN*Xes such as OS X - those structures begin with a *one-byte* length field followed by a *one-byte* address family field, not with a *two-byte* address family field.

So all the `UInt16` family fields in the sockaddr structures there don't match the layout of the structures in OS X - or in {Free,Net,Open,DragonFly}BSD.  They might not match in some other UN*Xes, either, even though they might match in Linux.

Whether this is what's causing your problem is another matter.

Comment: can you provide some documentation on these native C structures? maybe this would help to adapt the code. I'm not quite sure, where to start looking.

Comment: For OS X, [`struct sockaddr` and `struct sockaddr_storage`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2782.1.97/bsd/sys/socket.h), [`struct sockaddr_in`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2782.1.97/bsd/netinet/in.h), and [`struct sockaddr_in6`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2782.1.97/bsd/netinet6/in6.h).  `struct sockaddr_ll` is Linux-specific, and doesn't exist in OS X.  The same structures should be in all 4.4-Lite-derived OSes, including the BSDs I mention.

Comment: I updated the question with the changes I made according to the docs you provided. Unfortunately it still doesn't work...

Comment: Actually, that's *not* according to the C header files I linked to.  They have *two* fields at the beginning, which would be represented as `public byte sa_len;` and `public byte sa_family;`, in that order - or, if C# has that type, `UInt8` rather than `byte`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. For some reason I thought the lenght field would be irrelevant, so I did not consider it. It works now!

Comment: Please file this as a bug at [the SharpPcap ticket page](https://sourceforge.net/p/sharppcap/_list/tickets).